# Bash Script | Variable from Remote ssh not being filled

Tags: bash, ssh, service

The variable devstate1 is not being recognised correctly by the if statement
If I printf devstate1 it prints failed as expected.
I'm just trying to add the text "Stopped" to a variable.

```
devstate1=`ssh root@10.1.1.1 systemctl status application | grep Active | cut -c 12- | cut -c -7`
devstate2=0

if [ "$devstate1" == "failed" ]
then
    devstate2=Stopped
fi

printf $devstate2\n
```

devstate2 returns 0

I have also tried:

```
if [[ devstate1 == "failed" ]]
then
    devstate2=Stopped
fi
```

This works:

```
if [ "$devstate1" == "active" ] || [ "$devstate2" == "active" ]
then
    echo Aborted! Dev Service still active
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$stagestate1" == "active" ] || [ "$stagestate2" == "active" ]
then
    echo Aborted! Stage Service still active
    exit 1
fi
```

And I don't understand why that does and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, it was silly.

I didn't cut enough text off, so there was a trailing space!

Fix:

```
devstate1=`ssh root@10.1.1.1 systemctl status jira | grep Active | cut -c 12- | cut -c -6`
```

Comment: I suspect `cut -c 12-17` might work for you instead of `cut -c 12- | cut -c -6` since your code only tests for the 6-char strings `failed` or `active` but there's probably a better alternative using awk than grep+cut.

Comment: Sometimes you look at other peoples code and are just like, why are you doing it like that? You just did this to me, thank you! hah!